# How to tie Minitest spec to IntegrationTest / Rails data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

How do I set up a Minitest Spec so it has access to the same Rails data and methods that an `IntegrationTest` does?

I had been using the "old" Minitest style, and decided to add a new test file using the Spec-style.  However, this test file

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe "Post Controller" do
  describe "#index" do
    it "renders index view" do
      get posts_url
    end
  end # #index
end
```

fails with this error message:

```
Error:
Post Controller::#index#test_0001_renders index view:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `posts_url' for #<#<Class:0x00007fe064d71210>:0x00007fe064da8260>
    test/controllers/posts_controller_spec_test.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

I suspect I need to do something so that the spec is placed in the context of testing a controller (thereby making routes and other things available); but, I don't see how.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it according to the answer on this link [How to tie Minitest spec to IntegrationTest / Rails data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485904/how-to-tie-minitest-spec-to-integrationtest-rails-data)

Change "describe "Post Controller" do" to "class PostControllerSpec < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest"

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class PostControllerSpec < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  describe "#index" do
    it "renders index view" do
      get posts_url
    end
  end # #index
end
```